# Topology in $\mathbb R$ and characterization of open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Just curious about the following:
We know that open sets in $\mathbb R$ can be denoted as countable disjoint unions of open intervals.
Let's denote $O=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} (a_i,b_i)$

My problem is that if it is possible that $(a_i,b_i)$ cannot be "ordered". In other words, is it possible that for, say, $(a_1,b_1)$, we cannot find another component $(a_2,b_2)$ that is the "neighbor" of it, so there are no $(a_i,b_i)$ such that $a_1\leq b_1\leq a_i\leq b_i\leq a_2\leq b_2$? Intuition says yes but I have a hard time to write it rigorously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $O=(-1,0) \cup\bigcup_n (\frac  1{n+1},\frac1  n)$.

This is open because it is a union of open intervals. Consider  $(-1,0)$. This interval  has no immediate successor because for any interval $(\frac  1{n+1},\frac1  n)$ there is an interval $(\frac  1{m+1},\frac 1  m)$ which comes between $(-1,0)$ and $(\frac  1{n+1},\frac1  n)$: For this you only need to choose $m$ so large that $\frac 1 m <\frac1 {n+1}$ or $m >n+1$.

Comment: Could you please add more detail to your answer?

Comment: @MathGeek I have done that. Let me know if it is clear.

Comment: Yes, it is much more clear now.

Comment: Thank you! It makes perfect sense